# algoritmo de multiplicação por soma

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um trabalho que preciso criar um algoritmo que transforme produto em soma ou diferença e só posso usar os sinais `+`, `-` e os comandos `else`, `if`, `print`, `while` e `input`. Consegui fazer funcionar em multiplicação de números positivos, mas não consigo otimizar (Ex: `4x2= 2+2+2+2` não é otimizado, e `4+4` é otimizado) e acertar o sinal na multiplicação de números, negativo com negativo e positivo com negativo (Ex: `-10x-2= -20`, algo que está errado).

Segue abaixo as linhas de código que consegui fazer:

```
N1 = int(input('Digite um número'))
N2= int(input('Digite um número'))

if ((N1==0) or (N2==0)):
    print('0')
else:
    if (N1<0) != (N2<0):
     N1
    if N1<0:
     N1 =-N1
    if N1<0:
     N2=-N2
    if N1>N2:
        maior=N1
        menor=N2
    else:
        maior=N2
        menor=N1

    result=0
    Count=0

    if (menor>0):
        while (Count<menor):
            result=result+maior
            Count=Count+1
    else:
        while (Count>menor):
            result=result-maior
            Count=Count-1
    print(result)
    print(Count)
```

Comment: Eu vi um erro lógico, logo no começo, você tem as inversões dos sinais dos números lidos. Você primeiro checa se N1 é negativo e inverte se for, logo depois você checa se N1 é negativo de novo para poder inverter ou não N2. Isso acho que acaba sendo a causa do seu erro de -10 x -2 = -20

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299251/como-multiplicar-em-python-sem-o-operador-multiplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
def mul_to_add(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        return '0'

    negativo = (x * y) < 0
    x, y = abs(x), abs(y)
    x, y = min(x, y), max(x, y)
    op = '-' if negativo else '+'

    result = f'-{y}' if negativo else f'{y}'

    for _ in range(x - 1):
        result += f" {op} {y}"

    return result


n1 = int(input('Digite um coeficiente: '))
n2 = int(input('Digite outro coeficiente: '))
parcelas = mul_to_add(n1, n2)

print(f'{n1} * {n2} = {parcelas}')
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-424017-6333)</sup>

---

Segui os seguintes passos para criar meu código:

1. **Definir se o resultado será positivo ou negativo**.

   Em resumo, se os sinais dos operandos forem iguais, o resultado é positivo, senão negativo. Exemplo simples para facilitar o entendimento:

   ```
   (+1) * (+1) = +1
   (-1) * (-1) = +1
   (+1) * (-1) = -1
   (-1) * (+1) = -1
   ```

   Para calcular simplesmente multipliquei os números e verifico se o resultado é negativo.

   ```
   negativo = (x * y) < 0

   # também poderia ser
   negativo = (x > 0) != (y > 0)
   ```
2. **Guardar o operador que vou usar para separar os operando** nos resultados

   ```
   op = '-' if negativo else '+'
   ```

   <sup>Estou usando uma *expressão condicional* (veja mais na [PEP-0308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) ou na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)) mas você poderia usar um `if` normalmente.</sup>
3. **Pegar o valor absoluto dos números** usando a função [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), não vou precisar dos sinais pois vou printar os sinais manualmente.

   ```
   x, y = abs(x), abs(y)
   ```

   *Obs: Se você achar que é "trapaça" você pode definir sua própria função que funcionaria para este exemplo:*

   ```
   def abs(valor):
       if valor > 0:
           return valor

       return -valor
   ```
4. **Definir qual é o maior e o menor número entre os operandos**.

   Dessa maneira garantimos a "otimização" que você mencionou na pergunta, garantido assim o menor número de repetições possível.

   ```
   x, y = min(x, y), max(x, y)
   ```

   *Obs: Se você achar que é "trapaça" você pode definir sua própria função que funcionaria para este exemplo*:

   ```
   def min(valor_1, valor_2):
       if valor_1 < valor_2:
           return valor_1

       return valor_2

   def max(valor_1, valor_2):
       if valor_1 > valor_2:
           return valor_1

       return valor_2
   ```
5. Por fim, **repetir o maior número (`y`) pelo menor número de vezes (`x`)**.

   No meu código criei uma string com o primeiro número, e usei um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) para armazenar os operandos restantes.

   ```
   # cria string que será retornada como resultado da função
   result = f'-{y}' if negativo else f'{y}'

   # (x - 1) pois o primeiro operador já foi inserido
   # quando a string foi criada
   for _ in range(x - 1):
       # concatena os operandos no resultado
       result += f" {op} {y}"
   ```

---

## Código com comentários

```
def mul_to_add(x, y):
    # se algum operando é zero, já retorna o resultado
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        return '0'

    # booleano se o resultado é negativo
    negativo = (x * y) < 0

    # remove sinal do número pois serão printados manualmente
    x, y = abs(x), abs(y)

    # garante que x seja menos que y (garante resultado "otimizado")
    x, y = min(x, y), max(x, y)

    # operador para "juntar" os operandos
    op = '-' if negativo else '+'

    # cria string que será retornada como resultado da função
    result = f'-{y}' if negativo else f'{y}'

    # (x - 1) pois o primeiro operador já foi inserido
    # quando a string foi criada
    for _ in range(x - 1):
        # concatena os operandos no resultado
        result += f" {op} {y}"

    return result


n1 = int(input('Digite um coeficiente: '))
n2 = int(input('Digite outro coeficiente: '))

parcelas = mul_to_add(n1, n2)

print(f'{n1} * {n2} = {parcelas}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui quebrar a cabeça aqui e **acho** que solucionei o problema além de otimizar um pouco o código.

```
N1 = int(input('Digite um número'))
print()
N2 = int(input('Digite um número'))
print()

if ((N1==0) or (N2==0)):
    print('0')
else:
    maior, menor = [N1,N2] if N1 >= N2 else [N2,N1]

    result=0
    Count=0

    # print('menor = {} e maior = {}'.format(menor, maior)) # Puramente debug

    if (menor>0):
        while (Count<menor):
            result=result+maior
            Count = Count + 1
    else:
        while (Count>menor):
            result=result-maior
            Count = Count - 1
        Count = -Count
    print('Resultado = {}'.format(result))
    print('Repetições = {}'.format(Count))
```

[Link funcional no ideone](https://ideone.com/dzYwlo)

O que eu alterei:

1. Simplifiquei a inicialização: é totalmente desnecessário a verificação se ambos os números são negativos e converter cada um em positivo.
2. Removi as alterações de sinais dos números: Aquilo tava causando quase todos os bugs do programa.
3. Terceiro **IF** dentro do **ELSE** jamais será executado se continuar com o mesmo teste, pois N1 era negativo e foi convertido para positivo, então ele falharia no mesmo teste.

Comment: Acho que seria melhor incluir o código que alterou diretamente na resposta, mas mantendo na mesma o link para o Ideone

Comment: Podes melhorar a condição que verifica qual é maior: `maior, menor = [N1, N2] if N1 >= N2 else [N2, N1]`

Comment: Melhorado @NoobSaibot obrigado pela dica :D